# How to Merge SPListItemCollection results?

Tags: sharepoint

We are trying to merge the results of each SPListItemCollection into single SPListItemCollection.

**List.GetItems(SPQuery)** command will be placed inside the for...loop and it will be giving **SPListItemCollection** as output for each item. The each output needs to be merged and produce **single** SPListItemCollection.

I've been using the following method to iterate SPListItemCollection and add into other SPListItemCollection.After iteration, I found that resultset.count is always "0" and it's not appending any of the item(s).

After Setting "SPQuery.ViewFields", the resultset.count is returning the count and items are getting appended in the SPListItemCollection. But,  after setting "SPQuery.ViewFields" property, the below method is taking more (nearly 20 -30 mins for 15,000 records) time to append the items.

If I'm not setting the property, the method performing quickly in iteration but resultset.count is always "0".

```
        public static SPListItemCollection MergeCollection(List<SPListItemCollection> collections)
    {
        SPListItemCollection resultSet = collections[0];
        try
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < collections.Count; i++)
            {

                int j = 0;
                foreach (SPListItem listItem in collections[i])
                {

                    SPListItem item = resultSet.Add();
                    foreach (SPField field in collections[i].Fields)
                    {
                        if (field.InternalName != "ID")
                            item[field.InternalName] = listItem[field.InternalName];
                    }
                    j++;
                }

                logging.Add("Result Count {0}", resultset.Count())
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                

        }
        return resultSet;
```